# Workbook.BeforeSave Event, Determine what Type they are saving as

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a "template" which our devs have to fill out, and I want when they save it to run some custom behavior before the file is actually saved.  There are two cells that are formula determined. When they user in question is saving the populated file from the template into an xlsx, I want those cells to be the values not the formulas.  (This also means, I don't want the macros saved with the XLSX file either.)

A perfect example is the =TODAY() formula, which if you save a an excel file with that formula in a cell on 1 Jan 2020, when it is reopened on 1 Feb 2020, that cell will read 1 Feb 2020, not 1 Jan 2020 when it was created and saved.

Since the original file they will be opening is an xltx, it will force them to save it as an xlsx or xlsm.  I want the template (xltx) to have the formulas (and macros), but when they save it as the xlsx it should only have the values.

The VB for Copy & pasting values of cells instead of forumlas is basic and I've done that many times. The problem is, when I attempt to save the tempalte as the modified template (xltx) the BeforeSave event kicks off and changes the cells back to values instead of the formulas, defeating the entire purpose. (catch-22)

Is there a way to detect that I am saving the file as a xltx or is my only recourse to put a break point in the event macro and "skip" those lines when I'm saving the template?

Answer (score 3):

If you put a breakpoint in the `ThisWorkbook_BeforeSave` handler, you'll find that this breakpoint will be hit **before** the "SaveAs" UI is even displayed, and the `SaveAsUI` parameter will be `True`, and since `ThisWorkbook` is already saved, then its `Name` will include the file name and its extension.

So you can easily get the `.xltx` file extension, but the problem is that at that point nobody knows what the user means to be doing - namely, whether you mean to be saving the template itself, or a working copy of it: `BeforeSave` is fired too early for what you're trying to do.

You need to somehow have the meta-information already at your disposal.

If *you* are only ever a developer and aren't going to ever be saving the template as anything other than as a template file, then you can leverage environment variables - are computers given a name in your organization?

```
If Environ$("COMPUTERNAME") = "Your computer's name" Then Exit Sub
'...rest of the BeforeSave handler...
```

That gives you a way to run logic conditional to the `COMPUTERNAME` or `USERNAME` OS environment variable values.

Answer (score 1):

Use a class variable to record when the SaveAs dialog has been called and then use the `Workbook_AfterSave` event to make the adjustments.

[Workbook.BeforeSave event (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.beforesave)
SaveAsUI: True if the Save As dialog box is displayed due to changes made that need to be saved in the workbook.

```
Private hasSaveAsUI As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    Rem Check to see if the file has been saved as
    If hasSaveAsUI Then
        hasSaveAsUI = False
        Rem Do Something
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    hasSaveAsUI = SaveAsUI
End Sub
```

Comment: This is probably the simplest way to go about this, assuming saving the template under a different name via Excel's SaveAs UI isn't a scenario. Why `Rem` over `'` though?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon It might just be simpler to check the file name/extension in the AfterSave event.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon its not too late if the OP just needs to call the code that replaces the values from the `Workbook_AfterSave` event.